# Excel VBA UDF Formatting - Change argument values before calculation

Tags: function, vba, excel, arguments

I am trying to write a formula in Excel VBA to calculate: RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))

When any of the four arguments (A, B, C, D) are 0, I want to change their value to 0.5 in the calculation.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I believe my formatting is wrong or I'm going about it the wrong way. Any helpful tips would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried:

```
Function RR(A, B, C, D) As Double
If A = 0 And B = 0 Then
        A = 0.5
        B = 0.5
        RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))
    ElseIf A = 0 Then
        A = 0.5
        RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))
    ElseIf B = 0 Then
        B = 0.5
        RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))
    ElseIf C = 0 Then
        C = 0.5
        RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))
    ElseIf D = 0 Then
        D = 0.5
        RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))
    ElseIf A = 0 And D = 0 Then
        A = 0.5 And D = 0.5
        RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))
    Else:  RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))
    End If 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Function RR(A, B, C, D) As Double
    If A = 0 Then A = 0.5
    If B = 0 Then B = 0.5
    If C = 0 Then C = 0.5
    If D = 0 Then D = 0.5
    RR = ((A / (A + B)) / (C / (C + D)))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great. I kept the overall equation the same and it works fine.